# fs does not Write all received data file

Tags: node.js, sockets, filestream

My node.js script:

```
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');

var client = new net.Socket()

client.connect(PORT, HOST, function () {
       client.write('You can Send file\0');
       client.on('data', function (data) {
            // console.log(data); 
            var destinationFile = fs.createWriteStream("destination.txt");
            destinationFile.write(data);
       });  
 });
```

it is coded for receiving a file from remote HOST.
when i use `console.log(data)` its OK to log remote data file to console.
but for writing data to file its write one part of received data file.
How can write all data to file?
thanks

Comment: The first thing I ll try is to create the filestream outside of the `client.on` event, thy may overlap somehow.

Comment: thanks. in tiny test its OK. but written file has 16 bit more than real size. first of file has 16 bit of unknown data. how to ignore that?

Answer (score 3):

The cause of what you get:

`client.on('data')` is called multiple times, as the file is being sent in data-chunks, not as a single whole `data`. As a result on receiving each piece of data, you create a new file stream and write to it..

`Console.log` on the other hand works, because it does not create new *console window* each time you write to it.

Quick solution would be:

```
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function () {
       var destinationFile = fs.createWriteStream("destination.txt");
       client.write('You can Send file\0');
       client.on('data', function (data) {
            // console.log(data); 
            destinationFile.write(data);
       });  
 });
```

Also notice in the [net Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_port_host_connectlistener) on `net.connect` method:

> Normally this method is not needed, as net.createConnection opens the
>   socket. Use this only if you are implementing a custom Socket.

Comment: +1 because it s the good answer, but it feeled like comment poaching.

Comment: @DrakaSAN No offense node-brother. I saw your comment, it was correct, with some guessing, but correct. I assumed you left the subject as no answer was coming afterwards, so I summarized it up for the compleness. +1 to you too :D

Answer (score 2):

The problem you got is because you declare the filestream inside the event on, which is called each time a packet arrive.

```
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function () {
    var destinationFile = fs.createWriteStream("destination.txt"); //Should be here
    client.write('You can Send file\0');
    client.on('data', function (data) {
        destinationFile.write(data);
    });  
 });
```

> thanks. in tiny test its OK. but written file has 16 bit more than real size. first of file has 16 bit of unknown data. how to ignore that?

In your code, since client.on is called multiple time, multiple write happens in the same times, so it is undefined behavior for which write happens, in which order, or if they ll be complete.

The 16 bytes of unknown data are probably bytes from different packet writen one after the other in random order. Your tiny test work because the file can be send in one packet, so the event is called only once.

If you declare the filestream first, then call the write in client.on, the order of write and data are preserved, and the file is written successfully.

Comment: how to ignore first 16 bit of received data in code?

Comment: You still get 16 bytes of unknown data with the fixed code?